# Getting website not found in laravel homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have installed virtual box, vagrant, git bash. everything runs well. 
when I command 'vagrant up', no errors shows.

```
forhad@BlindMirror MINGW64 ~/Homestead (master)
$ vagrant reload --provision
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater] Removing hosts
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater] Checking for host entries
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
default: /vagrant => C:/Users/forhad/Homestead

 forhad@BlindMirror MINGW64 ~/Homestead (master)
```

but when I enter website address on browser, it shows http://laravel.dev is not available.

url containing port 2222 works, e.g   127.0.0.1:2222, it shows

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
```

on the browser.

no other url works,

Homestead.yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
  - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
  - map: C:/Users/forhad/Homestead
     to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
  - map: laravel.dev
     to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
  - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

#ports:
#   - send: 93000
#    to: 80
#   - send: 7777
#    to: 777
#     protocol: udp
```

Comment: im using laravel/homestead on windows 8.1

Comment: did you edit your `hosts` file to tell your browser where to look for `laravel.dev`?

Comment: yes, i did it. @Jeff

Comment: problem fixed, i just changed laravel/Homestead 0.4.0 to laravel/homestead 0.5.0....  now it works fine..

5hour before from now they released laravel/homestead 0.5.0......